# Which proof assistants implement Church's rule?

Tags: proof-assistant, tactic, software-request, constructive, program-extraction

[Church's rule (CR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties#Related_properties) is one of the hallmarks of constructive mathematics, and is an [admissible rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule) in a wide variety of constructive theories (you might consider CR to be a requirement for constructive theories). Note that unlike the axiom [CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_%28constructive_mathematics%29), Church's rule does not prove any anti-classical results.

> Let $\eta$ be an [admissible numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering). CR is admissible for a theory $T$ iff for every formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that $$T \vdash \forall x \in \mathbb N. \exists y \in \mathbb N. \phi(x, y)$$ there exists $e \in \mathbb N$ such that $$(*) \text{ } T \vdash \text{$\eta_{\bar e}$ is total} \land \forall x \in \mathbb N. \phi(x, \eta_{\bar e}(x))$$

My question is **which proof assistants have implemented this rule?**

---

Notes:

- I'm fine if $e$ is taken to be a member of some other discrete data structure (like strings or finite trees) instead of $\mathbb N$.
- It doesn't need to be an official feature, a tool or patch from a third-party is fine.
- What I'm looking for is **not just program extraction** (although it is related to it). The implementation must both output $e$ *and* a proof of $(*)$. Program extraction typically outputs $e$ but not a proof of $(*)$. In particular, if $\phi$ is a function, the proof assistant has proven it is a [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) and can apply theorems about computable functions to $\phi$. (Likewise, there are some systems that assume the axiom CT but don't compute $e$. They also don't count.)
- $(*)$ is proven *within $T$*, so the software can't add any extra axioms (like that $T$ is arithmetically sound) when proving it.

Comment: I assume you don’t want T to be classical right?   Because then this would hold, right?

Comment: Actually, I’m really confused why this doesn’t hold constructively too, in say Coq.  Can’t we easily calculate e from $\phi$ in such a way that the proof that $\eta_e$ is total follows straight from the proof of the former statement?

Comment: @JasonRute if $T$ is classical, than the church rule can't hold because $T$ will be able to show the existence of uncomputable functions. For example, PA proves "for all x there is a y such that y is the xth busy beaver number", in which case $e$ won't exist.

Comment: Wait, can phi be any formula?  What are the conditions on phi?  (I realize I misread Wikipedia and thought phi was quantifier free.)

Comment: Also when you say “implement”, it not enough for you that CR is true (in say maybe Agda or Coq), but you want there to be some extraction mechanism that automatically turns a proof of the first statement into a proof of the second, right?

Comment: @JasonRute there are no conditions of $\phi$ other than there being a proof of $\forall x.\exists y. \phi(x,y)$. The reason CR can exist is that in constructive proofs can be turned into programs. The program is found by analyzing the proof, not by analyzing the formula $\phi$.

Comment: @JasonRute by "implement" I mean an actual piece of software. I am very confident that CR is correct in Agda and Coq. CR is correct in [IZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory), for example. But I don't know of any software for performing it automatically. (It is always computable for recursively enumerable theories.)

Comment: Is $\exists$ allowed te interpreted as $\Sigma$?

Comment: @AndrejBauer yeah that's fine. In a system with both, CR using either $\exists$ or $\Sigma$ works.

Comment: It was a trick question: From $t : \Pi (x : A) \Sigma (y : B) .\, \phi(x,y)$ we can get a closed term $f = \pi_1 \circ t : A \to B$ and a proof that it works, and we're done.

Comment: (Like, the version with $\Sigma$ should probably be referred to as CR! (since the equivalent axiom is called CT!). But I'd also interested in implementations for CR!.)

Comment: @AndrejBauer hmm, it's a very subtle issue but I think technically this approach would require $\eta$ to be an interpreter for $T$ terms, which I imagine is impossible to use for Gödelian/Tarskian reasons. $e$ is supposed to part of a discrete data structure, but $f$ is a function. The term underlying $f$ can be represented by a natural number, but turning it back into a function requires an interpreter.

Comment: You can use meta-programming features tu turn `f` into code (a discrete data structure). And since we're talking about a rule that only applies to sentences, we *must* go meta-level at some point.

Comment: Actually, how is $\eta$ supposed to work? If it's an interpreter for $T$ then there's a problem.

Comment: @AndrejBauer $\eta$ could just be an interpreter for Turing machines. That doesn't run into any logical issues (although there are probably more convenient numberings that also avoid logical issues).

Comment: It cannot be just that, or else you would introduce partial maps into your type theory.

Comment: @AndrejBauer okay so my notation was perhaps a bit misleading. $\eta$ should actually be thought of as a relation, not a function. [This formulation of CT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_%28constructive_mathematics%29#Formal_statement) is more specific about this (and also applies to CR).

Comment: That makes more sense. My observation still stands: it's more productive to implement reflection, quoting and other meta-level techniques, and leave the actual comittment to CT (either as an axiom or as a rule) to people who want it.

Comment: OTH, people do care about the fact that every closed term of type $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ denotes a computable map. Even more, proof assistants are very good at computing with them, so it remains questionable what the advantage of CR would be (other than extracting maps from totoal relations, which is a form of choice).

Comment: @AndrejBauer yeah I figured it was a bit extravagant (but perhaps there was a tiny proof-of-concept proof assistant that implemented it?). A use case I had in mind: if you have or are in the process of formalizing [computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory) in the proof assistant, CR is a convenient way to prove a function of computable, so having it as a built-in tactic is convenient. The requirement that the proof assistant actually produces $e$ is just a preference for the proof assistant being able to compute things (just adding an axiom is obviously easy).

Comment: You should ask a separate question: how to formalize computability theory? The answer is very nice and cannot be done justice in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give a look at [*A Certifying Extraction with Time Bounds from Coq to Call-By-Value Lambda Calculus*](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/entities/document/10.4230/LIPIcs.ITP.2019.17) by Yannick Forster and Fabian Kuntze. They define a set-up in Coq where using tactics they can transform a Coq function into a deeply embedded λ-calculus term, and also provide facilities to relate this function to the original one. There is much more work of this group around similar ideas, including synthetic computability theory using CT (see Yannick's PhD thesis for an overview), all kinds of synthetic computability/complexity results, and work on MetaCoq, which gives facilities for quoting and unquoting Coq terms – although not (yet?) about the relation between the quoted term and the original one.

Comment: Metacoq already proves that erasure preserves the computational behaviour of the source Coq term for first-order functions, see [this module](https://github.com/MetaCoq/metacoq/blob/coq-8.17/erasure/theories/ErasureCorrectness.v). Since this is the hardest part, I think that CR can be obtained by chaining several theorems lying around the development.

Comment: But wait, this is not what I meant? I was talking about having a relation between `t` and the output of `MetaCoq Quote t.`.

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer you would like to hear, but that would be "no proof assistant" (to my knowledge). The first reason is that Church's rule does not hold for classical theories but the constructive proof assistants are all designed to be agnostic about excluded middle, and so will not commit to Church's rule. The second reason is that Church's rule in its original form is at best of a very limited use in practice, while at the same time its implementation would heavily influence the internals of a proof assistant.

Precisely because proof assistants are so conservative and general, anyone is free to implement Church's rule. Some of the mechanisms supporting such an exercise already exist, for example:

- [MetaCoq](https://metacoq.github.io), and in particular its subpart Template-Coq, allows meta-level manipulation of Coq code, provides representation of Coq code in Coq, etc.
- [Agda reflection & metaprogramming](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/reflection.html#metaprogramming) similarly offer meta-level capabilities for reifying and evaluating Agda code.

Perhaps someone has already used these tools to do it?

Lean has nice meta-programming functionality, too. It might be possible to use it, if you can somehow avoid using its non-classical axioms.

Comment: "The first reason is that Church's rule is anti-classical." Are you sure? I thought CT (the axiom) was anti-classical but CR (the inference rule) wasn't? (Like, CR isn't admissible for in any classical theory, but it doesn't allow you to derive any anti-classical principles.)

Comment: Ah yes, we must be careful. In any case, because CT isn't admissible for classical theories, that would be reason enough for agnostic implementors of constructive proof assistants to dislike it. But the main reason really is that it's just not worth doing. If you're going to invest energy into implementing this sort of thing, it's better to just implement program extraction or some such.